# Arcmap Addin 10.3.1: Cancel/control loading of addins, based on a condition

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.3, add-in

I'm creating Add-in for arcmpa in C# , for 10.3.1. These add-in are to help with client workflows for the business needs.

I need to be able to control whether an add-in can load or not. (control of workflow)

I understand that you can on-demand load etc, but want to do something like:

if mxdFilename = blah OR configfile.fullname exists 
 load
else
 ignore.

Or allow only certain mxd to 'know' the path location for the addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just experimenting with something similar a few weeks ago. I hope I'm wrong on this and someone can show us a better method, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to keep the Add-In fully out of a certain MXD. What we experimented with was testing for the current document title and then firing off an event to continue whatever the Add-In does *if* it's an MXD we want the Add-In to function within.

```
protected override void OnStartup()
{
    if (ArcMap.Application.Document.Title == "this.mxd" || ArcMap.Application.Document.Title == "that.mxd")
    {
        WireDocumentEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm adding a bool binary variable to the mxd. I'll check that on load, to see if it exists. So thank you for the direction